# Creating an active page within a channel

Tags: templating

I need some advise about the best way to achieve this.

My site is set up with a Channel called 'Product' for example.

I then have entries within this section

- Product A
- Product B
- Product C

Only one of these products will be active at once.

All links on the site for 'Product' will need to link to the active product page (A, B or C).

The way I'm thinking of doing this is having a lightswitch on the Product pages to state which is the current (active) one.

I can't get my head around how this might work at the moment so any advise would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a single template that is displayed when you visit `/product` and set `entry` to be the first entry in the Product channel that is live.

`{% set entry = craft.entries.section('products').status('live').first() %}`

All you need to do then is disabled all product entries apart from the product you want to display.

---

**UPDATE**: To avoid duplicate content or different content on the `/product` page you could redirect to the current product entry page `/products/product-a` using

`{% redirect entry.url %}`

Comment: This is a nice solution thanks. Only concern is you then have duplicate content at page /product and on the entry at /product/product-a for example

Comment: To avoid that you could set the `/products` template to redirect to `entry.url`. `{% redirect entry.url %}`

Comment: Super! thank you.